# Power to outlet but outlet not working

Tags: electrical

Power is good going to breaker and power is good at outlet but not working when something is plugged in.

Comment: Outlet might be worn out or there is a loose wire.  Turn off the breaker and check no power before replacing it.

Comment: Please edit the question to describe how you know that power is good at the outlet. 
 What tests did you do?  Also swap the outlet with another one that works and describe the results.  If the problem stays with the bad outlet, throw it out.

Comment: An outlet needs neutral as well. You may need to test with a voltage tester to verify you have both hot and neutral.  If you are in the US or Canada you need 110V or about between hot and neutral.

Comment: What does a [3-light tester](https://amzn.to/3FzPcTk) show?

Answer (score 1):

Depending what you mean or how you are measuring, **voltage present when nothing plugged in, but things plugged in don't work** is typical of a high resistance between the supply and the outlet, typical of a bad connection that's not completely open, but which drops the voltage as soon as anything tries to draw power from the outlet.

If there are backstabs used on any devices, suspect them first, and change those to side-wiring with screws, but it can also be a loose wirenut or even worn-out receptacle contacts. An actual broken wire (in this case being held together by the insulation enough to  connect, but not well) is possible, but exceedingly rare. It's almost always a bad connection.

The bad connection can be at any point from the breaker panel to the receptacle in question, on either the hot or the neutral wire. If you know the route the circuit takes, it's between the last working device and the first affected device, generally AT one or the other unless there's a junction in-between.

If you are measuring voltage, try measuring the voltage at the other half of the outlet when trying to use something plugged in, assuming it's a usual duplex and not half-switched or on a MultiWire Branch Circuit.